# How to obtain the source location in an overload of operator new

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, new-operator, delete-operator

I'm making a little memory leak finder in my program, but
my way of overloading new and delete (and also new[] and delete[])
doesn't seem to do anything.

```
void* operator new (unsigned int size, const char* filename, int line)
{
    void* ptr = new void[size];
    memleakfinder.AddTrack(ptr,size,filename,line);
    return ptr;
}
```

The way I overloaded `new` is shown in the code snippet above. I guess it's something with the operator returning void* but I do not know what to do about it.

Comment: "doesn't seem to do anything":  what do you mean?  You overloaded the operator, but you haven't *overridden* the default operator new, so "new x" calls the default new while "new (filename, line) x" calls your overloaded version.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
void* ptr = new void[size];
```

Can't do that. Fix it.

Never ever try to overload new/delete globally. Either have them in a base class and derive all your objects from this class or use a namespace or a template allocator parameter. Why, you may ask. Because in case your program is more than a single file and using STL or other libraries you are going to screw up.

Here's a distilled version of `new` operator from VS2005 `new.cpp`:

```
void * operator new(size_t size) _THROW1(_STD bad_alloc)
{       // try to allocate size bytes
   void *p;
   while ((p = malloc(size)) == 0)
    if (_callnewh(size) == 0)
     {       // report no memory
        static const std::bad_alloc nomem;
        _RAISE(nomem);
     }

     return (p);
}
```

Comment: Actually, I had a good reason to do that once. We had a compiler "issue" where it was using heaps in an unsafe way across DLL boundries. The fix was to create a custom version of "new" that used a specific named heap.

Comment: Why did you not file a bug and instead chose to play with fire?

Comment: We did. The response we got back was something along the lines of "DLLs don't work very well cross-process in our system". We eventually quit using them, but in the short term this fixed the problem.

Comment: LOL. Anyway, there are better alternatives to globally overloading new/delete as I have mentioned already.

Comment: There will be no problems with libraries and everything else if you will not try to deallocate memory that wasn't allocated by you (and vice versa). And STL can use custom memory allocators. 
We use custom new/delete operators in debug builds for long time and have no problems.

Comment: Yes, very true. But this is difficult to manage. We too use custom allocators (and have been using for a while now). I mentioned STL custom above I believe.

Comment: "Why did you not file a bug and instead chose to play with fire?" If you ever had to work with a vendor you would know the answer to that question. Some are better than others, some would just say "thanks for the bug report - it will be fixed in the next version - oh by the way your license doesn't cover the next version..." Some may even go so far as to say "it's not a bug, it's a feature" as was stated by @T.E.D.

Answer (score 61):

Maybe you can do what you want with a little bit of preprocessor magic:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void* operator new (size_t size, const char* filename, int line) {
    void* ptr = new char[size];
    cout << "size = " << size << " filename = " << filename << " line = " << line << endl;
    return ptr;
}

#define new new(__FILE__, __LINE__)

int main() {
    int* x = new int;
}
```

Comment: should it be `size_t` instead of `unsigned int`? I believe on some platforms these types are not equivalent.

Comment: Why `void* operator new (size_t size, const char* filename, int line)`'s 1st argument is `size_t`? If I want to override `delete` operator, what should I write?

Comment: @naive231: `new` always takes a `size` as its 1st parameter. It receives the byte size of the data that is being allocated (in this example, `sizeof(int)`).  Anything extra passed to `new` is passed in secondary parameters

Comment: Doesn't this torch placement new?

Answer (score 13):

I think the problem here is that your new's parameter profile doesn't match that of the standard operator new, so that one isn't getting hidden (and is thus still being used).

Your parameter profiles for new and delete need to look like this:

```
void* operator new(size_t);
void operator delete(void*, size_t);
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem relies with the two arguments that you have added to the overloaded new operator. Try making filename and line global in some way (or member variables if you're overloading new and delete for a single class). That should work better.