# Can overloaded new operator receive args to pass to the object's constructor?

Tags: c++, qt, operator-overloading, new-operator, qimage

I see a lot of C++ libraries dealing with dynamic memory allocation this way:

```
Qimage* _image = new QImage(width, height, QImage::Format_RGB888);
if (!_image)
{ 
    // Failed!
}
```

I find it **interesting** that it is possible to check whether an object was succesfully allocated or not with a simple code like `if (!_image)`.

1) I wonder if this is a **native feature of the standard `new`** or if this is only possible if you overload `operator new` with your own implementation.

2) How would I go about implementing `operator new` in this case, where it **receives arguments for the object's constructor** and it returns NULL in case width && height are 0?

Did I get any of this right?

Comment: Indeed, fixed! Thanks @James.

Comment: To be honest, it seems weird that the return value of new would be based on the quality of the parameters. I would personally expect either a) the constructor to throw an exception on bad input, or b) to create a function that checks the parameters and returns 0 if the input is malformed....but that's just me.

Comment: That's essentially what I was interested in doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you see is wrong. [**new** doesn't return null anymore but throws std::bad_alloc instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550451/will-new-return-null-in-any-case)

[Overloading new](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/operator_new.html) has an example. [You don't need to deal with constructor arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583003/overloading-new-delete)

What you are trying to do is done kindof by **[make_shared](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee410595.aspx)** in C++11

Comment: But an overloaded `operator new` could do what I'm proposing, right?

Comment: Yes, it could. But new don't get the arguments to constructor. It is called before the constructor.

Comment: I don't think an overloaded operator new is allowed to return null unless it is nothrow (or in C++11, has a throw() specification).  There may be other cases, but I'm pretty sure plain old new is never allowed to return null.