# How to save pointer to redefined operator?

Tags: c++, memory-management, new-operator, redefinition

I have overloaded new and delete operators. I want to save pointers to 'old' `new` and `delete` to call it into 'new' `new` and `delete`. For example:

```
#include "h.h"
void * operator new ( size_t size, /*args*/ ) throw (std::bad_alloc)
{
    void * p = 0;
    p = original_new(size); //calling for 'old' new
    //some code
    return p;
}
```

And the similar operator `delete`.

So, I'm trying in my header file to type the following:

```
static void * (*original_new)(size_t) = ::operator new;
static void * (*original_new_arr)(size_t) = ::operator new[];
static void (*original_delete)(void *) = ::operator delete;
static void (*original_delete_arr)(void *) = ::operator delete[];
```

It is successfully compiled, but I have core dump on start.
It is possible to call `malloc` in `new` bad it is really **bad** idea. It is possible to call `new(std::nothrow)` but it is bad too.

Comment: Check this link in stackoverflow     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/583003/overloading-new-delete

Comment: dont overload new and delete globally, and how about to use malloc and free?

Comment: @Yola: Define "globally". If the overload-declaration is not visible in a unit of translation, it can't be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to save pointers; defining a placement new operator (any
`operator new` function which takes more than one argument) doesn't
remove the existing operators; it just overloads them.  To call the
standard operator new function from a placement operator new function:

```
p = ::operator new( size );
```

Note that you do *not* want to do this if your placement new returns
anything but the exact address returned by `::operator new`.  Otherwise,
`delete` won't work.  If you use any placement new that return anything
other than a pointer returned by `::operator new`, you need to define a
new global `operator delete` (because this is the one that will be
called), which in turn means that you have to define a new standard
`operator new` as well, so that it will work correctly with your new
`operator delete`.  In order to avoid having to implement all of the
memory management yourself, use `malloc` and `free` in your
implementations.

Comment: I have big project with memory leaks, I don't want to modify code a lot. Now, if I `inlude "h.h"` in cpp file it obtains a redefined `new` and `delete`, if I don`t include - it uses 'old' operators.
 

You are right. But, it seems impossible to overload `operator delete(void *p)` to `operator delete(void *p, char *file, int line)`.
So, calling 'old' `delete` from 'new' `delete` is infinite recursion.

Comment: Replacing global standard new and delete doesn't require any changes in your code, or even recompiling; all you have to do is ensure that your new versions come before the standard library in the list of files to be linked.  With regards to `delete`, you can (and should) define a placement delete if you define a placement new.  But most of the time, it will still be the standard delete which is called, so if you have a special new, you have to provide a non-placement delete as well to handle it, and if you define a non-placement delete, you have to define the non-placement new as well.