# how gnu c++ implement new and delete

Tags: c++, new-operator, delete-operator

I just see some declarations in libstdc++-v3, but can't find the definitions. Does the `new` and `delete` just encapsulate `malloc` and `free` ? Where can I find the definitions of `new` and `delete` ? And why can't I find the `bits/c++allocator.h` include in `bits/allocator.h` ? So many strange things in gcc.

Comment: I have heard the `malloc` and `free` are implement with `ptmalloc` in `glibc`, I want to know does `new` and `delete` use `ptmalloc` as well or some other strategy ?

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/libsupc%2B%2B/new_op.cc?view=markup

Comment: c++allocator.h can be any of the files in https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/config/allocator/ , that makes it easier to pick a different default when configuring gcc.

Comment: Download and read the [source](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/tree/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3).

Answer (score 4):

Although C++ Specification states that developers should avoid using legacy old malloc/free way to allocate memory, C++ language itself can do nothing with memory allocation. new/delete act like wrapper to malloc/free with C++ type-safe features and throw expections when malloc return NULL. That why “new” never return NULL but expectations. They do the job for you.

C++ use C routines like glibc, libc for system-level operation. In Linux, the only way to “actually” allocate memory is to call brk() and mmap(). All language include Java and Python call malloc() or lower-level api to allocate memory and call free() when recycle "garbage".

To sum up, the answer for your question is "new/delete call malloc/free and handle expections".

Comment: Do you mean exceptions?

Answer (score 2):

> Does the new and delete just encapsulate malloc and free ?

Check out [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240212/what-is-the-difference-between-new-delete-and-malloc-free).

> Where can I find the definitions of new and delete ?

Find the description of new and delete [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/).

I hope someone else can help you on your third question.

Comment: I add a comment for complement just now. Actually, I want to konw how gnu c++ implement `new` and `delete` exactly in its source code. Sorry for not express my question clearly.

Answer (score 0):

They are handlers that can be redefined. The "malloc" and "free" are parts of that structure. They can be redefined to improve memory managements.

[overloading new/delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583003/overloading-new-delete)