# How to force use of explicit allocator type parameters when using containers and strings

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I'd like to force the use of explicit allocator template type parameters when using standard containers, including string.

Obviously I can do this by modifying the headers that come with the compilation system to remove the defaults for the allocator parameters.  But this introduces a maintenance issue and also (for some compilation systems) might even require the use of custom-compiled runtimes.

What is the easiest way to do this within the language?  Preferably, by #including a standard header (e.g., `<string>`) and preceding or following it with some kind of code ... or maybe wrapping the #include of a standard header in a header of my own (and leaving the original `<string>` out of the include search path).

(Motivating example:  I want to implement region-based memory allocation throughout my server/service, and thus always want to use allocators that statefully refer to specific heaps.  I can use stateful allocators with C++11 and later, and with some pre-C++11 compilation systems.  I will provide a bunch of my own typedefs and alias templates to make things less painful for the programmer in this system. I want the restriction that the "default" allocator is never used to be enforced by the compilation system - not by a SCM submit rule.  I don't have to worry about "malicious" programmers trying to defeat the restriction, I just don't want someone to make the easy mistake of not specifying an allocator each and every time.)

Comment: How about just https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583003/overloading-new-delete

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky - that's either global or per-class.  Doesn't give "region based" as in a group of related allocations where the lifetimes - especially the end-of-life - are all related.  Plus per-class would be fairly intrusive in modifying standard library classes.

Answer (score 2):

You could use aliasing:

```
template <typename T, typename A> // No default value here
using StdVector = std::vector<T, A>;
```

and then use `StdVector` instead of `std::vector`.

Comment: But can I then _prevent_ the direct use of `std::vector` - with its defaulted allocator parameter?  (IOW, how do I manage to make the full decl/defn of `std::vector` available to this alias template but prevent it from being used where the alias template is visible?)

Comment: That doesn't prevent indeed to use directly `std::vector`.