# Abort in wifstream destructor

Tags: c++, abort, codecvt

The following C++ code gets a mysterious error ("Debug Error!...abort() has been called") when the `return` is executed. This is Visual Studio 2017 15.6.3, and the program is a 64-bit debug build, running under 64-bit Windows 7. What is causing this error, and how can I fix it?

```
wifstream inFile;

std::codecvt_utf16<wchar_t, 0x10ffff, std::little_endian> cv1;
inFile.imbue(std::locale(inFile.getloc(), &cv1));
return 0;
```

Tracing through with the debugger shows the message is coming from the disassembler instruction

```
call        std::basic_ifstream<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t> >::`vbase destructor'
```

The last entry on the stack, other than `msvcp140d.dll`, `vcruntime140d.dll` and `ucrtbased.dll` is

```
    MyApp.exe!std::basic_ifstream<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t> >::`vbase destructor'() C++
```

The purpose of this code is the input file `infile` is Unicode (little-endian), and I am reading it into a `std::string` variable.

Comment: This "program" is not a program; it's a code snippet. Add just enough code so that it compiles and runs and shows the problem.

Comment: If you're trying to use the stream you imbued using `cv1`'s address after it has been destroyed, its likely to fail.  But we can't tell that until we've seen your [mcve].  You've been here for long enough to understand why one is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::locale` maintains a reference count for each facet that is associated with it.  The `std::locale` constructor you are calling will increment a reference count for the `std::codecvt_utf16` object you are passing in, and then `std::locale`'s destructor will decrement that reference count.  When the reference count of the `std::codecvt_utf16` falls to 0, it will be destroyed via the `delete` operator.  That is why you are getting the abort error - when the `std::wifstream` destructor is cleaning up the `imbue`'d locale, the locale's destructor tries to `delete` something that was not allocated with the `new` operator to begin with.

Do this instead:

```
inFile.imbue(std::locale(inFile.getloc(),
    new std::codecvt_utf16<wchar_t, 0x10ffff, std::little_endian>));
```

See the example in the [`std::codecvt_utf16`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf16) documentation on [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com).

Comment: Tnx for your prompt (and correct!) response. When I compile your code, I get an  `error C2661: 'std::_Crt_new_delete::operator new': no overloaded function takes 3 arguments`. This comes from `#ifdef _DEBUG /
#define new DEBUG_NEW /
#endif`` that Visual Studio puts into a dialog source file. Removing that compiles and runs without error. So there is some Visual Studio incompatibility.

Comment: The code I presented doesn't pass 3 arguments to `new`, it should compile no matter what `new` is defined as. Otherwise VS is breaking core language functionality. What is `DEBUG_NEW` defined as? I don't use VS.

Comment: `#define DEBUG_NEW new(THIS_FILE, __LINE__)`, and `#define THIS_FILE __FILE__`. And, yes, it is a bug in VS, which I will report. Nothing wrong w/your code!

Comment: The only way that such a `DEBUG_NEW` could work like this is if there is an overloaded `operator new` in scope that takes 3 parameters: `void* operator new (size_t size, const char *filename, int line)` (see [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/583079/65863)). It sounds like that is not actually the case in your situation, which would explain the compiler error you are seeing.