# Access object inside an operator c++

Tags: c++, this, new-operator

I'm overloading the "new" operator in order to keep track of every allocation. I want it to print the size of the allocated memory, as well as the type of the object that is allocated.

I've come up with something like this:

```
void* operator new(size_t size) {
  std::cout << "Allocating " << size << " bytes.\n";
  return malloc(size);
}
```

but I have no clue on how to print the type of the object.
Thank you for the help!

Comment: AFAIK you are out of luck.  It is the new expression that deals with the type, not the new operator.

Comment: You can't get type information here.  You could try something as discussed in this Q/A https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583003/overloading-new-delete

Comment: At that point there is no object yet, so there is nothing you can find the type of. `operator new` is only a memory allocation function.

Comment: `operator new` is also called by `std::allocator<T>`, so there's no simple solution anyway. That could be in response to `std::vector<U>::reserve`, in which case you would only be allocating raw bytes.

Answer (score 0):

There is no type involved at all. You specify nowhere any type - what you do is just memory allocation in bytes. So, the type is always an array of `size` bytes.