# Why the operator delete does not get called?

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

I've created the following demo program regarding operator `new` and operator `delete`.

```
void* operator new(size_t size)
{
    void* ptr = std::malloc(size);
    std::cout << "allocated [" << size << "] bytes address [" << ptr << "]" << std::endl;
    return ptr;
}

auto operator delete(void* addr) noexcept -> void
{
    std::cout << "freed address [" << addr << "]" << std::endl;
    return std::free(addr);
}
```

In main, I try to do this:

```
int main()
{
            auto ptr = new int(10);
            delete ptr;
}
```

However, I could see the log of operator new but could not see that of operator delete

```
allocated [4] bytes address [0x192bcc41900]
```

It is interesting that for a class customized operator new and operator delete, there is no such problem.

```
class A
{
public:
    A()
    {
        std::cout << "A::ctor" << std::endl;
    }
    ~A()
    {
        std::cout << "A::dtor" << std::endl;
    }
    void* operator new(size_t size)
    {
        void* ptr = std::malloc(size);
        std::cout << "A::new allocated [" << size << "] bytes address [" << ptr << "]" << std::endl;
        return ptr;
    }

    void operator delete(void* addr) noexcept
    {
        std::cout << "A::delete freed address [" << addr << "]" << std::endl;
        return std::free(addr);
    }

private:
    int m_int = 10;
};
```

I can see both logs when I new a A class object and then delete it.

```
auto ptr = new int(10);
delete ptr;
```

What's wrong with this?

Comment: See [overloading new/delete](https://stackoverflow.com/a/583040/12002570), `void operator delete(void*, size_t);`

Comment: So far my rule of thumb was, to use `operator new` and `operator delete` only if I need access to raw memory. Overloading them for some special memory management (e.g. shared memory) is possibly also a legit use case. But there are a ton of overloads and you might have gotten the wrong one. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete

Comment: Your code works as-is on the version of Clang in Mac 12.x (Monterey) (and other compilers) - what are your compilation flags and compiler version?

Comment: Your code gave the expected output https://godbolt.org/z/eTrjMvY14

Comment: Can't reproduce either.   Out of curiosity, why are you using different return styles i.e. preceding return type for `operator new()` and trailing return type for the `operator delete()`?   Does the behaviour you see still occur if you change `operator delete()` to use the preceding return type (i.e. `void operator delete(void *address) noexcept`)?

Comment: I am using CLion 2022.1 on Windows, and this is my CMakefile

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(test_new_delete)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_executable(test_new_delete main.cpp)

Comment: Perhaps this is a clion issue. Are you sure you see all the output of the program? Try adding some prints at the end of `main`.

Comment: Yeah, perhaps it is CLion issue. I am pretty sure I have seen all the logs. The same program did yield expected results (both operator new and operator delete logs are printed) on Linux.